# sudo sh -c ‘echo “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner” >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list’ not woking

Tags: package-management, skype

I'm trying to skype on ubuntu 14.04, but when I type:

```
sudo sh -c ‘echo “deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner” >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list’
```

It says "Permission denied."

Please help, or tell me another way to get Skype.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here has nothing to do with redirection, it's that you've copied curly quote characters. They are not the same as straight quotes (which the terminal understands as special characters) so the command does not mean the same thing at all.

This is largely the fault of the website you've copy-pasted the commands from (you should let them know).

To fix, simply replace the curly version with their straight counterparts:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list'
```

Yes, `tee` might look nicer but there's nothing wrong with redirection.

---

There was some question about whether this really was the cause. It is, but I'll prove it. The redirect in the original command is being interpreted first. Bash attempts to open a write handle (as the current user) on the output file *first* and fails.

```
$ sudo afoijaf2 > /rawr
-bash: /rawr: Permission denied
```

That's why we don't see a command not found. `afoijaf2` here is clearly non-existent and `‘echo` is also clearly an invalid command. Neither are being executed —`sudo` hasn't even run— because Bash failed to get a write handle. That errors out first.

Comment: More importantly, enabling the Canonical repositories can be done using the Software Sources GUI. In fact the entire process of installing Skype can be done via GUI. Why use a command line method, which you don't understand and may end up with you borking the system, when an easy alternative exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can not redirect with sudo, use tee

```
echo foo | sudo tee -a file
```

There are other ways as well

Comment: You *can* redirect with `sudo`. `sudo sh -c 'foo >> file'` is a perfectly valid way of doing it... Provided you use the right quote characters.

Comment: That works, but technically you are running a root shell (sudo sh) and re-directing within the root shell. `sudo foo >> file` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Skype with GUI**

for Skype you should go to [download_skype](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/), you probably need
[multiarch_version](http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb)
but I can't know that in advanced. It is something based on your ubuntu version.

Long story short when the **.deb file** is down on your system , **open and install**
with **ubuntu software center** and basically that was it !